# Question : Dart/Flutter passing parameters not working

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, parameters

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I am studying it by myself and don't have much experience. :) thanks for your help!

I wanted to change a map to JSON.

I tried to follow https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#creating-model-classes-the-json_serializable-way this example, but it is not working as I expected.

assume that the class I am using is

```
class User {
   String? name;
}

User({name});
```

and I have a json as `String userJson = {"name":"Dart"}`

I tried to decode the json to a Map and change that to User instance.

When I do `print(userJson["name"])` it prints "Dart", but then if I put that into the user class

```
User user = User(name: value);
print(user.name);
```

it prints null.

**Why is the value not saved into user?**

When I pass the value as

```
User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   name = json["name"];
}

User user = User.fromJson(map);
print(user.name);
```

then of course it works well.

as I said before,
**why can't I pass the "name" value to the User parameter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.name` in the constructor instead.

Like so:

```
class User {
  String? name;
  User({this.name});
}
```

Without `this.`, the `name` from the constructor, is different from the `name` in the class.

Answer (score 1):

you need construct inside the `User` class.

Example:

```
class User {
  String? name;
  String? address;
  int? age;
  User({this.name, this.address, this.age});
}
```